# How to completely remove Magento Product URL re writes

Tags: import, product-urls

I have imported in a large number products into a store that is not live (Magento CE:1.9) but now need to correct their URLS.

Ideally I want to correct the correct URLS via an CSV import (system > import> data flow profile)

If I truncate the 'core_url_rewrites' table and then check in the admin (catalog > url re writes) it appears that the re writes have gone.

If I then import in the new URLs they appear in the admin (Product > URL path) but then reindex the URLs, they do not update to the new ones - the original ones are retained.

It appears that the 'core_url_write' contains the custom re-writes not the system (or other) ones.

How can either remove the fully remove the product URLs, or even completely remove the product and their URLs so they can be re imported and use their corrected ones.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you've actually set the URLs on the right scope on import.

You've got a minimum of two scopes (website and store) that the URL can be defined on.

If you have imported your new URLs under a different scope, then when you reindex you'll have URLs generated for both.

Comment: Thank you - yes this was exactly the issues. I was importing to the 'default' not the 'english' store view - so when the site was browsed on the front end the urls reflected the store view ones. To fix this, we have deleted the other store views and imported in the URLs again (selecting the store scope on the import option) and it all looks correct now.

Comment: Great. Be sure to mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied.